# What's the format for writing an html code inside .py file?

Tags: html, python-3.x

I want to put the html code inside .py file, I removed the .html extension file and wrote the html code in .py file, but when I'm running the server it's printing even the triple quotes or whatever I write with the code. Removing the quotes is giving me an error. I want to create modules of .py files instead of html templates.

Here's my website:
[image: Here's the image showing triple-quotes] 
and here the code I have for it:
[image: My code]

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Do not post images of code (why should we have to go through and retype it if we want to test something)? Please put it right in the question.

Comment: Why do you want to replace html templates with python files containing html strings? If you explain a bit of your reasoning, we may be able to help you find a better way (based on what you have described so far, this doesn't seem like a great idea).

Comment: Instead of writing html templates, my manager told me to create modules of .py files like deleting the about.html and create about.py containing the same html code and printing the same output, so is there any way I can do it?